# Puppeteer-sharp hangs when running as webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, puppeteer-sharp

I want to use the puppeteer-sharp libary in a webservice which is deployed in an IIS environment.

I already know that the download of the chromium is successfully (I can find the file on my computer). Unfortunately, as far as I know from debugging, the Task bf.DownloadAsync does not terminate.

```
        [Route("f")]
        [HttpGet]
        public void F()
        {
            g().Wait();
        }

        public static async Task g()
        {
            BrowserFetcher bf = new BrowserFetcher(new BrowserFetcherOptions()
            {
                Path = "C:/Users/user/Downloads"
            });
            await bf.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = true
            });
            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            await page.GoToAsync("http://www.google.com");
            await page.ScreenshotAsync("C:/Users/user/Downloads/myOutPutFile.png");
        }
```

I expected that the task to terminate, resulting in a png-File in my download directory. The actual result is that bf.DownloadAsync never terminates.

Comment: Is the downloaded zip being extracted?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: You shouldn't use `.Wait();` you should async all the way.

Comment: Thank you! That was the right answer.